# Error with transferspreadsheet command

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Attempting to import data from Excel file (vrtSelectedItem) to Access table (MAF), but receive "Type Mismatch" error on the DoCmd line.

The data is in a sheet named "For Export", but I'm not sure I indicated that correctly.  Could be something else on the line, though.

Additionally, the data is in a named range, "ExportRange".  Is it possible to use the name instead of specifying the cells?

```vb
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
    Dim xl As Object
    Dim wb As Object, ws As Object
    'Dim data1 As Variant

    'Select Excel file
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Select one or more files"
        .InitialFileName = InitPath

        If .Show = True Then
           Set xl = CreateObject("excel.application")

            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
                DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, MAF, vrtSelectedItem("For Export"), 0, "B1:B72"
            Next
        End If
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data you want to import is in a named range (*"ExportRange"*), use that name as the *Range* argument.  And in that case, don't even mention the sheet name.

The *TableName* argument should be a string value.  I assumed you want to import the data into a table named *"MAF"*, so quoted that table name.

```vb
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acImport, _
    SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
    TableName:="MAF", _
    FileName:=vrtSelectedItem, _
    HasFieldNames:=False, _
    Range:="ExportRange"
```

I don't see the value of `CreateObject("excel.application")`. It seems you only need a straightforward `TransferSpreadsheet` operation so you shouldn't need to create Excel application instances.

Comment: Works like a champ!  Thanks.